# matching URLs in a markup language via Regex

Tags: regex, url, mediawiki

I'm working on a code matching URLs (doesn't have to be valid) in a markup language, you can simply import URL or you can add it between [ ]. I give you some examples:
1-http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
2-[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page Title]
3-[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(Main_Page) Title]
4-(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page)
5-[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page]
I need three regexes, one for URLs in brackets (no. 2,3,5) , another for URLs that they are not in bracket(1,4) and one for all of that
first and second one are easy I did it:

```
notInside = '\]\s<>"'
notAtEnd = '\]\s\.:;,<>"\|\)'
regex = r'(?P<url>http[s]?://[^%(notInside)s]*?[^%(notAtEnd)s]' \
r'(?=[%(notAtEnd)s]*\'\')|http[s]?://[^%(notInside)s]*' \
r'[^%(notAtEnd)s])' % {'notInside': notInside, 'notAtEnd': notAtEnd}
```

but problem begins with the third one, one the URL started with a parentheses (or anything but bracket) like number 4, the regex shouldn't match the ")" at the end of URL but sometimes people use ")" at the end of URL and put in bracket, the regex must match this ")" like number 3. I can't write two separate regexes for the third one and combine results

Another thing: I will post your help in free software code, so please imply that's ok I publish your codes in MIT license. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

This regex will:

- match strings urls found inside square brackets, round brackets, and no brackets
- Each type of bracketed match will be captured in a different capture group

`\[(https?:\/\/(?:(?!\]).)*)\]|\((https?:\/\/(?:(?!\)).)*)\)|(https?:\/\/(?:(?!\s|$|\Z).)*)`

[image]

## Example

Live Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/g7o1xdOGB5

**Sample Text**

```
1-http://1en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
2-[http://2en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page Title]
3-[http://3en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(Main_Page) Title]
4-(http://4en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page)
5-[http://5en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page]
```

**Matches**

```
[0][0] = http://1en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
[0][1] = 
[0][2] = 
[0][3] = http://1en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page

[1][0] = [http://2en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page Title]
[1][1] = http://2en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page Title
[1][2] = 
[1][3] = 

[2][0] = [http://3en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(Main_Page) Title]
[2][1] = http://3en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(Main_Page) Title
[2][2] = 
[2][3] = 

[3][0] = (http://4en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page)
[3][1] = 
[3][2] = http://4en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
[3][3] = 

[4][0] = [http://5en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page]
[4][1] = http://5en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
[4][2] = 
[4][3] =
```

## Alternative

I'm not sure how well lookbehinds work in media wiki but you could try this

`(?<=\[)https?:\/\/(?:(?!\]).)*(?=\])|(?<=\()https?:\/\/(?:(?!\)).)*(?=\))|https?:\/\/(?:(?!\s|$|\Z).)*`

[image]

Given the same sample text, this will put all the captures into group 0

Live Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/2o9aebq1OZ

## License and free use

Stack Overflow policy says: user contributions licensed under [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)

Comment: I tried the alternative regex out but it still matches closing parenthesis in markdown files where links are written in format of square brackets and round brackets. Example: [hello](https://hello.com)

Comment: Can you provide an example via one of the many online regex editors like http://www.rubular.com/r/g7o1xdOGB5. I suspect that you're not including the 'http://' which is required for this regex to work.